# How to simplify noncommuting multiplication of KroneckerProducts

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm using NCALgebra. I was wondering if there is a way to simplify

```
KroneckerProduct[a, b]**KroneckerProduct[c, d]
```

to become:

```
=KroneckerProduct[a**c, b**d]
```

The same way we get it for dot product in Mathematica, which can be done using TensorExpand:

```
KroneckerProduct[a, b].KroneckerProduct[c, d] // TensorExpand
```

results in:

```
KroneckerProduct[a.c, b.d]
```

Comment: When you say: "I was wondering if there is a way to get..." Do you mean "Expand the matrix product on the left to give the matrix on the right."?

Comment: You say "The same way we get it for dot product in Mathematica, which can be done using TensorExpand." Can  you post this?

Comment: @pdmclean I edited the post, hopefully makes my question more clear.

Comment: An ugly way of doing this is: convert  NonCommutativeMultiply-> Dot, then do TensorExpand, and then do Dot->NonCommutativeMultiply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you  want to achieve is to simplify noncommuting products of KroneckerProduct, you may simple define a rule

```
KroneckerExpand = {KroneckerProduct[a_, b_] ** 
KroneckerProduct[c_, d_] :> KroneckerProduct[a ** c, b ** d]}
```

which yields  for

```
KroneckerProduct[a, b] ** KroneckerProduct[c, d] //. KroneckerExpand
```

the output

```
KroneckerProduct[a**c, b**d]
```

or

```
KroneckerProduct[a, b] ** KroneckerProduct[c, d] ** 
KroneckerProduct[e, f] //. KroneckerExpand
```

with the output

```
KroneckerProduct[a**c**e, b**d**f]
```

etc. This is indeed the same as TensorExpand provides for Dot-Products, but allows you to use Dot-Products and ** in the same expression. On the other hand the current solution is clearly limited to applications of KroneckerProducts only (and can't in this form be used for other objects subject to ** products).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is defining a function as

```
Mconv[expre_] := Substitute[TensorExpand[Substitute[expre,NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot]], Dot -> NonCommutativeMultiply]
```

Using this:
`KroneckerProduct[a, b] ** KroneckerProduct[c, d] // Mconv`

we get:

```
KroneckerProduct[a ** c, b ** d]
```

Though I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this.